# Replace string while considering the last character (number) value

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I am starting with Python. I need to replace the strings from 'Old' column basis on a condition. If the first character of the string is `A` I need to replace it with `Z`, but I also need to add 1 to value of the last character

For example:

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| A2 | Z3 |
| C4 | C4 |
| B4 | B4 |
| A5 | Z6 |
| A1 | Z2 |

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Old': ['A2', 'C4', 'B4', 'A5'], 'New': ['Z3', 'C4', 'B4', 'Z6']})
df['New'] = df['Old'].str.replace('A','Z')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom function:

```
df['New'] = df['Old'].apply(lambda x: x if x[0] != 'A' else f'Z{int(x[1:])+1}')
print(df)

# Output:
  Old New
0  A2  Z3
1  C4  C4
2  B4  B4
3  A5  Z6
```

Comment: Perfectly, will study lambda